# Why do I have such high overhead when creating tables in MSSQL7?

Tags: sql-server

I have an old system running MSSQL7. It takes about 10.5 seconds to create the table below and another 30 seconds to add the index. Is there anything I can do to decrease these times?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [queue] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [seqNum] [numeric](12, 0) NOT NULL ,
    [cTime] [char] (14) NOT NULL ,
    [msg] [char] (255) NULL ,
    [status] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [socket] [int] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
 CREATE  INDEX [search] ON [dbo].[MyTable]([queue], [seqNum], [status]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

 CREATE  INDEX [new] ON [dbo].[MyTable]([queue], [status]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: are you getting auto-grow events?

Comment: I don't show any, it's not very active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having any locking issues on the system objects going on when this is running?

What's the load on the disks look like?

Any reason that you are running a version of SQL Server that is way out of support?  There have been a LOT of performance improvements between SQL 7 and SQL 2008.

Comment: Oh trust me, if I could upgrade I would.

Comment: I'll accept that as a valid answer.  I've been there. How about the questions I asked?

Comment: I couldn't get back to this yesterday, but when I try an profile creating the table again, I get reasonable times. Yesterday, read and writes were fairly high for the query itself, but disk load on the server as a whole is pretty minimal. There does seem to be lock on master.dbo.spt_values table pretty frequently